# Link vba to a user input worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub CleanData()

Dim MessageAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim EachRange As Range
Dim TempArray As Variant
Dim col As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet


uSheet = InputBox("Define the sheet name")
Set ws = Worksheets(uSheet) 'Define the sheet name
uRange = InputBox("Define the range")
Set rng = Range(uRange)


For Each EachRange In rng.Areas
    TempArray = EachRange.Value2
        If IsArray(TempArray) Then
        For rw = LBound(TempArray, 1) To UBound(TempArray, 1)
            For col = LBound(TempArray, 2) To UBound(TempArray, 2)
                If Len(TempArray(rw, col) < 1) Then

                ElseIf IsNumeric(TempArray(rw, col)) Then
                    TempArray(rw, col) = CDbl(TempArray(rw, col))
                ElseIf Format(TempArray(rw, col) = "//") Then
                Else
                    TempArray(rw, col) = uRange.Trim(TempArray(rw, col))
                End If
            Next col
        Next rw
    Else
      End If

    EachRange.Value2 = TempArray

  Next EachRange


'Code Ran Succesfully!
  MsgBox "Your data cleanse was successful!", vbInformation, "All Done!"

End Sub
```

I'm not sure how to link this to a user input sheet. everything else works fine. The reason I'm doing this is to link this vba to a command button on a different sheet. The user specified range works fine but I can't seem to figure out how to include a worksheet into the code.

Comment: If I understand, you probably need to connect the `Range(uRange)` to the worksheet you expect it, `ws.Range(uRange)`?  Otherwise, `rng` will refer to the range on the `ActiveSheet` which is not necessarily going to be what the user puts as `uSheet`.

Comment: Yess. It worked perfectly!

Comment: Is there a way to stop the dates from being shifted around? The dates are currently stored in the dd/mm/yyyy format but as general. the code reads it as a number but i want it to ignore this format

Comment: Try wrapping it in `Format([date],"dd/mmyyyy")`?

Comment: same result. so far it only worked if i changed all the dates as text